# appengine transaction lock

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want make sure that one thing about the [transaction](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions.html) lock of GAE. In the documentation it said:

> All datastore operations in a transaction must operate on entities in
>   the same entity group if the transaction is a single group
>   transaction, ....

So while a txn is running, it will lock only every entries of that single entity group, won't lock every entry of models which are used in the transaction. Is it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GAE uses [optimistic locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) - that means that nothing is locked in transaction, instead it check last update time, and if it's after time you have started your transactions - it will throw exceptions (and rollback your data). It's described at '[What Can Be Done In a Transaction](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#what_can_be_done_in_a_transaction)'

Comment: But to answer the original question, however misphrased: Contention only applies to entities in the same entity group, not all entities of a given model, yes.

Comment: 'What Can Be Done In a Transaction'  link is dead, can't find any reference anywhere to google datastore's timestamp based optimistic locking, beginning to wonder if it even does it anymore